# How to flash validation errors to session in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, session, redirect, fetch-api

The built in behavior for flashing back validation errors in Laravel does not seem to be working for my use case.

I have a (React) form that posts it's data via fetch API using this method, which reloads or redirects the page with (hopefully) any session data after the response is returned:

```
fetch(props.register_route, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': props.csrf,
            },
            body: data,
        })
        .then((result) => {
            return result.json();
        })
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            window.location.href = result.url;
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

In my controller, I validate this data but if I structure it as follows, the errors are not available as $errors in the resulting page

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);
        }
```

However if I manually flash the errors to the session and return a url instead of a redirect, suddenly the behavior works.

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
            Session::flash('errors', $validator->errors());
            return response->json([
                'url' => route('register'),
            ], Response::HTTP_NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
        }
```

I feel as if I must be doing something incorrectly here to have to use this workaround. I could also manually send the errors back in the response, which may be the right way to structure things in the long run.

Comment: Can you update your question with your controller source code?

Comment: Using React.js, you should definitely be sending back the errors, not a redirect. The whole point of React.js and similar (reactive) JS frameworks is to limit page reloads. It may also be helpful to brush up on the differences between server-side code and client-side code.

Comment: @matticustard In this case I am using react just for a wizard-form and front-end validation using Yup/Formik, ultimately the rest of the app is not a SPA and redirections will need to occur. It does seem based on most comments that explicitly sending back the errors in the response body is the way to go, though I still wonder why one of the above methods does not actually store any session data before the redirect

Comment: Laravel can't push new data into an already loaded web page — you must use CLIENT-side code for this. Also, a browser session and a server session are two different things. Session flash data is part of the SERVER session and is only available via PHP (server-side code) on the server. It is not automatically injected into the browser session.

Comment: @matticustard I believe there may be some confusion. This form resides in a PHP/Blade template with a section that renders any PHP validation errors. When the URL is returned from the response, the page reloads and then displays that data. I'm not trying to get access to the session in an already loaded page.

Comment: The flashed session data only exists once.  That's the point of flashing.  You attempted to return a redirect as a page response in Laravel, so the flashed data is now gone if you reload again.  That's why your first attempt did not work, but the second (manual method) did.  Because you only initiated a single page response.

Comment: @matticustard I see, in the first attempt the redirect in laravel is the first HTTP request, and the client side redirect is the second, so no more flash data. In the second method, I'm sending the response but the client redirect is now the first HTTP request and so has the flash data. That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

when you are calling api from javascript or front end applications like `Reactjs,Angular,android etc..` .So it expect return result should be in json  format so it should be like

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json( $validator->errors(),422);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for catching that I was not returning the response as json. I will likely end up doing something like this, but still wonder about the session issues I was facing.

Comment: @KyleR.session will not be used in api.only token based authentication .if my answer helps dont forget to accept and vote

Answer (score 1):

if you not calling Method from direct laravel blade then pass response in JOSN Format.
like
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#json-responses

Or

**make one ResponseManager File**

```
<?PHP

namespace App\Libraries\utils;

class ResponseManager {

public static $response = array('flag' => true, 'data' => '', 'message' => '', 'code' => 01,);

public static function getError($data = '', $code = 10, $message = '', $flag = false) {
    self::$response['flag'] = $flag;
    self::$response['code'] = $code;
    self::$response['data'] = $data;
    self::$response['message'] = $message;
    return self::$response;
}

public static function getResult($data = '', $code = 10, $message = '', $flag = true) {
    self::$response['flag'] = $flag;
    self::$response['code'] = $code;
    self::$response['data'] = $data;
    self::$response['message'] = $message;
    return self::$response;
 }}
```

Define in **config/app.php**

```
//custom class
    'ResponseManager' => App\Libraries\utils\ResponseManager::class,
```

and then *use in whole project*

**Error Message Like**

```
   if ($validation->fails()) {
        $message = $validation->messages()->first();
        return Response()->json(ResponseManager::getError('', 1, $message));
    }
```

**Success Message Like**

```
return Response()->json(ResponseManager::getResult(null, 10, "Success"));
```